# How to remove a specific property in CSS engine?

Tags: css, properties

I am making a Chrome extension and need to know if can do the following. 
I want to remove a specific CSS properties like (filter, opacity, etc). The property must remain in the CSS or HTML, example:  `style="filter:blur(3px)"`, but this not should have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand correctly, you can use jQuery's .css() method ([link](http://api.jquery.com/css/)). Here is an example:

CSS:

```
.box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.box').css('background-color', 'none');
```

Comment: No friend, a guy of 5 yo can make it (background-color:none). I want to remove any CSS property in the browser Chrome or Firefox to become obsolete. Thanks again :).

Comment: Please clarify your intentions. It appears you want to preform CSS manipulations without any Javascript. That is impossible, and for a good reason. If you do want to use Javascript, please give us a specific example of what you want to create.